# Best practice in link element syntax 2022?

Tags: html, syntax, hyperlink

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
```

I think using the slash at the end is called voiding. W3c doesn't show it, but some official sites and my teachers do. What should be the one version I should use?

Comment: A `/` is a slash not a dash (`-`) and it is *allowed* on void elements but is almost always a waste of bytes.

Comment: Thank you @Quentin . Indeed, I meant slash. Thank you for the reply. :)